# Is it possible to publish a node.js app to Azure from linux?

Tags: linux, node.js, azure

I am trying to publish my node.js application to windows azure. It is developed and tested on my Arch Linux but the problem is how i am supposed to publish it to azure. There is some sort of sdk for windows and i found something in npm called azure (probably something to do with the azure sdk). But there is little to none documentation.

Nevertheless, is it possible to publish applications to azure from linux? And if so, how do i do it. Is there any good resources to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways you can do this working on the local machine in addition to using Cloud9

1. You can use the web portal + git: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/create-a-website-(mac)/
2. You can use our CLI tools. On Linux the easiest way to get them is via "sudo npm install -g azure.". You can find more in this guide: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/command-line-tools/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Cloud 9 IDE from your browser:

http://c9.io/

The publish process works very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/deploying-with-cloud9/